JavaPOS not working. jpos.JposException: Control not opened
I am using Maven and having issue in printing "Hello World" with EPSON TM-U220B printer. I have downloaded the Driver in official website and tried to print using SetupPOS_Launcher.bat and it worked. so the communication is working.
then now I have installed Maven and install this dependency:
C:\Users\POSUser.m2\repository\com\epson\javapos\1.14.1\javapos-1.14.1.jar
and have this code in my Main.java
package org.test.mavenproject3;

import jpos.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        POSPrinter posPrinter = null;
        try {
            // Create a POSPrinter object
            posPrinter = new POSPrinter();
            
            // Open the printer device (replace with your printer name)
            posPrinter.open("EPSON_Printer");
            posPrinter.claim(1000);  // Claim the printer
            posPrinter.setDeviceEnabled(true);  // Enable the printer

            // Use the constant from POSPrinterConst for printing
            posPrinter.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "Hello, world!");

            // Release and close the printer
            posPrinter.setDeviceEnabled(false);
            posPrinter.release();
            posPrinter.close();
        } catch (JposException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (posPrinter != null) {
                try {
                    posPrinter.close();
                } catch (JposException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

but it didnt work. im thinking. can you guys give me a download link for JavaPOS library to also check and test any versions? TIA.

It is off topic in here to ask for resources: libraries, tutorials etc. I would recommend you changing your question and adding whatever error is being shown to you. Better yet, remove the try catch block and let the program break, copy the stackTrace then add it to your question.
